# Watir and Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, watir

In my webapp I have a simple textfield. To this textfield I have a jQuery function which will be always executed on every **keyup**. With this function there is an Ajax request assigned which loads every time the result of the SQL-Query. My code is equivalent to the code of 
[RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax). Now I'm testing my webapp with Selenium. With this line of code

```
browser.text_field(:id => 'textfield').set("Search text")
```

the text will be written and the content will be changed. After it should click on a link which is placed on the dynamic content with this code

```
browser.a(:id => "link").click
```

The problem now is that the click event won't be executed. Has somebody an idea what the problem could be? Or maybe an example with Watir and Ajax?

Comment: I did not understand what is the problem here. When you click a link nothing happens? And what should happen? Could you create a sample page and provide the URL?

Comment: You say "Now I'm testing my webapp with Selenium. With this line of code" but then what follows is Watir code..  which is confusing me a bit.. is that just a missing edit to the question?

Comment: Have you tried this with Watir-Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

you can use capybara  method.

```
click_link("link")
```

for ajax set `:js => true` in you test case

http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question and now I'll realize it with Watir. Do you have any idea?

Comment: why down vote dont you read original question? Watir was not mentions in original question!!

Answer (score 0):

Without an example site to test against it's hard to be sure but I will throw out a few potential solutions for you

If the client side javascript is looking for onkeyup events, you may need to fire one after setting the contents of the field.  You can do that via the .fire_event method

You could just be looking at a timing issue.  If the nature of the link is changing as a result of the input, it's possible that Watir is firing off the two comments in rapid succession and the client side code is still in the midst of doing it's thing (especially if there is back and forth between the jquery code and the webserver that as happening as that also induces networking delays.  You may need a brief sleep between commands (brute force) or to wait for a particular element to assume an expected state (a little more work but also a bit more robust and not subject to breaking is the delay exceeds your sleep duration)

I'd suggest executing the commands manually via IRB (you could just cut and paste from your script as needed) to be able to watch the state of the browser, and note any delay in updating the screen/DOM after a particular action.  If stuff works properly in IRB but not when executed via a script it's often taken as confirmation of a timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the original Watir/Firewatir I would try getting it to hover over the link before it attempts to click it.

I've had this problem previously with links that appear after typing into an "autocomplete" field (i.e. it attempts to guess at the text you want by filtering down from a huge list of possibilities).

Try this:

```
browser.wait_until{browser.link(:id => "link").present?}
browser.link(:id => "link").fire_event("onmouseover")
browser.link(:id => "link").click
```

If it works, try it without the `.fire_event("onmouseover")`, because it could just be that it's trying to click the link before it's visible and failing to do so.

If this is actually a question regarding "Selenium" (wrongly labelled Watir) then ignore all of the above, because I that is an application I've never used.